# C basic question about defining static arrays and macros

Tags: c, compiler-errors, static, syntax-error, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to define some arrays, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define int N=50;
#define size (N+2)*(N+2)
#define IX(i,j) ((i)+(N+2)*(j))
#define SWAP(x0,x) {float *tmp=x0;x0=x;x=tmp;}

int main()
{
    static float u[size], v[size], u_prev[size], v_prev[size];
}
```

It says, when compiling:

```
|9|error: storage size of 'u' isn't constant|
```

if i change #define int N=50; to #define N 50 it says:

```
|2|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant|
```

Does somebody have an answer?

Comment: `#define int N=50;`? That's not how macros are defined.

Comment: WIth your macro definitions, you end up with this line: `N=50; main()` which doesn't look like you want this.

Comment: And `static u[size], ...;`? What is the *type* for the array elements?

Comment: With the code in the first snippet, there is no value `N` that you could use to define `size`.

Comment: "I'm trying to initialize an array" Well, no. You don't have any initializers for your arrays. What you are currently trying is to define some arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want the arrays to be float arrays

Comment: @Brinax: In that case, change `static u[size]` to `static float u[size]`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Be making the variables `static` they will be initialized to all zeroes. But I agree that might be considered badly formulated.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it's still doesn't work, same error message

Comment: @Brinax: Did you also change `#define int N=50;` to `#define N 50`? If you make the two changes that I mentioned, then I believe that your code will compile.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel #define N 50 says:
expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code in your questions. That will remove the problem, making your questions and problems seem useless.

Comment: @Brinax: If I perform the two changes that I mentioned, then your code compiles on both gcc and clang. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/z3YTs51h7) is a demonstration.

Comment: Again, ***don't fix the code in your question***. That will make your question useless to future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take `u[size]` as an example. If you start replacing the text with the macro the following will happen:

-> `u[size]`

-> `u[(N+2)*(N+2)]`

and that's it... That is it is not a constant, because `N` is not a constant (and undefined).

Now if we take your suggested answer, it should work. What I think you may have is `#define N 50;`. Notice the semicolon at the end. If you replace the last line, above, with that macro, the new result will be:

-> `u[(50;+2)*(50;+2)]`

which is invalid syntax.

The last thing you're missing is a type from your declaration. Might want to put `int` or some other type after `static`.

It seems like you're missing the fundamentals of macros. Your first macro `#define int N=50` is bad, ver bad. Anytime the word `int` is mentioned in the code below it, it will get replaced with `N=50`.

Comment: i still have the error:
|2|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant|

Comment: Remove `#define int N=50;`. This macro is replacing the keyword `int` with `N=50;` everywhere. Your `main` function signature will be the following after the preprocessor step `N=50; main()`

Comment: @Brinax Check the *lines* reported in your error messages. I'll bet it's not where you expect. If you define `int` as a macro, then think about what happens with `int main()`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude error is on line 2:
```
#define N 50
```

Comment: @Brinax Please read the ***full*** and ***complete*** error output. You code will have multiple errors, some of them references line `2` because that's where the macro is defined. Other related messages will point to line `7` which is the `main` function declaration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok i've found that the errors come from others line, none of these were in main function, i'm coding with code::blocks and it's a bit misleading how the things are presented in the build console

Comment: @Brinax one more thing, be careful with macros. The preprocessor step happens before the compilation, hence the name, and your macros will "alter" your code so then your compilation errors might be a little cryptic, or misleading. Before I became more comfortable with macros, I'd write out the entire line of code first (no macros) and then start pulling out macros one at a time.